# Powershell search until next pattern

Tags: regex, powershell, pattern-matching

I am trying to parse through a .txt file. Sample content is below.

Here is code I have done so far. My intention is :

If line matches '-----STRING (S) FOUND -------'  then get string in column 3 to 11 in $string1.

Then until next '-------STRING FOUND----', match if '.COM' is present or not.

**Final Output will be like :**

```
MEM1     .COM

MEM2     .COM


$foundCall = $false
$string1 = $null
# Script to find email

gc "D:\download\yoghaem2.txt" | % {
  if ($_ -match '----------- STRING(S) FOUND -------------------')
   {
    $string1 = ^(.{8}) # 3 to 11 column
  }  
  elseif ($string1 -ne $null) {
    if ($_ -match "\.com") { $foundCall = $true }
  }
}

if ($foundCall) {$string1} 



      MEM1 CONCAT#(7)       ----------- STRING(S) FOUND -------------------

          82  //    PARM=('%@ M=TEMPMSL ROMSL=(MSLPRO,MSLSYS)',
          83  //          '@% CMD="GENERATE MEMBER(&NAME) SYSTEM(.COM/OS)"')
          97  //    PARM=('%@ DSN SYSTEM (&DB.&TO)',
          98  //          '@% RUN PROGRAM(DCGBINIT) PLAN(DCGV330)',
          99  //          '@ LIB(''&CSPNODV..AELOAD'')',

      MEM2 CONCAT#(7)       ----------- STRING(S) FOUND -------------------

          63  //    PARM=('%@ M=TEMPMSL ROMSL=(MSLPRO,MSLSYS)',
          64  //          '@% CMD="EXPORT MEMBER(&NAME)',
          65  //          '@ TARGET(&XNAME) TYPE(.COM)"')

      MEM3 CONCAT#(7)       ----------- STRING(S) FOUND -------------------
```

Comment: Note that `-match` uses regex and you have special characters in your search string that normally need to be escaped -> `()`. You can use [regex]::escape("") to help with this. Right now I don't think it will match the literal brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Switch, and best guess at what it is you want.

```
#Create test file
(@'
MEM1 CONCAT#(7)       ----------- STRING(S) FOUND -------------------

          82  //    PARM=('%@ M=TEMPMSL ROMSL=(MSLPRO,MSLSYS)',
          83  //          '@% CMD="GENERATE MEMBER(&NAME) SYSTEM(.COM/OS)"')
          97  //    PARM=('%@ DSN SYSTEM (&DB.&TO)',
          98  //          '@% RUN PROGRAM(DCGBINIT) PLAN(DCGV330)',
          99  //          '@ LIB(''&CSPNODV..AELOAD'')',

      MEM2 CONCAT#(7)       ----------- STRING(S) FOUND -------------------

          63  //    PARM=('%@ M=TEMPMSL ROMSL=(MSLPRO,MSLSYS)',
          64  //          '@% CMD="EXPORT MEMBER(&NAME)',
          65  //          '@ TARGET(&XNAME) TYPE(.COM)"')

      MEM3 CONCAT#(7)       ----------- STRING(S) FOUND -------------------
'@).split("`n") |
foreach {$_.trim()} | Set-Content testfile.txt


#Script starts here:
Switch -File ./testfile.txt -Wildcard
 {
   '*----------- STRING(S) FOUND -------------------*'
   {
      $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
       Mem = $_ -replace '^(\S+).+','$1'
       Found = $null
      }
   }

   '*.com*'
   {
     $result.found = '.COM'
     $result
   }
 }



Mem                                                                 Found                                                             
---                                                                 -----                                                             
MEM1                                                                .COM                                                              
MEM2                                                                .COM
```